# Docker Registry v2 api return strange code

Tags: docker

The screenshot shows what I get from http api

When I enter:

```
curl -X GET registry.yiqixie.com:5000/v2/
```

It returns something that I can't read:

[image: from https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCrNS.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a remote registry, you should access it [through https](https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/registry/deploying/#configure-tls-on-a-registry-server).
And you can add a `-v` in order to see the encoding of the answer.

```
curl -k -v -X GET https://registry.yiqixie.com:5000/v2/_catalog
```

Make sure [your bash supports utf8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16169/7490).

Comment: @Night Great! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.

Comment: Sorry for that, it's my first time to use stackoverflow